# How to specify 0..1:0..1 relation in SQL so that Prisma db pull gets it right

Tags: mysql, prisma, introspection

I have two tables, `MiniStore` and `Store`; They are in a relationship that if a `Store` needs a position, it has to use `MiniStore`. Not every store has a reference to `MiniStore`, and there are many `MiniStore`s that are not having `Store` (I use them to display markers on a map where some store exists).

```sql
CREATE TABLE `MiniStore` (
  `idMiniprod` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `lat` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `lng` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`idMiniprod`),
  KEY `Logo_idx` (`idLogo`),
  CONSTRAINT `miniprod_prod` 
    FOREIGN KEY (`idMiniprod`) 
    REFERENCES `Store` (`idMiniprod`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1250 COLLATE=cp1250_czech_cs;

CREATE TABLE `Store` (
  `idProd` smallint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Prodejna` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `idMiniprod` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idProd`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idMiniprod_UNIQUE` (`idMiniprod`),
  KEY `prod_idMiniprod_idx` (`idMiniprod`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1250;
```

```
model MiniStore {
  storePositionID Int   @id @default(autoincrement()) @map("idMiniprod") @db.UnsignedInt
  logoID          Int   @map("idLogo") @db.UnsignedSmallInt
  lat             Float @default(0) @db.Float
  lng             Float @default(0) @db.Float
  logo            Logo  @relation(fields: [logoID], references: [logoID], onUpdate: Restrict, map: "MiniProd_Loga")
  store           Store @relation(fields: [storePositionID], references: [storePositionID], onDelete: Cascade, map: "miniprod_prod")

  @@index([logoID], map: "Logo_idx")
}

model Store {
  storeID         Int            @id @map("idProd") @db.UnsignedSmallInt
  name            String         @map("Prodejna") @db.VarChar(60)
  storePositionID Int?           @unique(map: "idMiniprod_UNIQUE") @map("idMiniprod") @db.UnsignedInt
  shortNumber     Int            @map("PKod") @db.UnsignedInt
  storePosition   MiniStore?

  @@index([storePositionID], map: "prod_idMiniprod_idx")
}
```

**What I want is to have the relation from `MiniStore` to `Store` also optional.**